# Homebrew OpenCV 32-bit on Mac 10.7.5

Tags: macos, opencv, homebrew, 32-bit

I am trying to make a 32-bit build of OpenCV on Mac 10.7.5 using Homebrew. I an trying to do this so that I can access a USB webcam via the 32-bit Macam driver from within OpenCV.

Brew Doctor:

```
$ brew doctor
Your system is raring to brew.
```

Brew config:

```
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git
HEAD: 56d86e070a60b9deac092a844993332945855027
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7.5-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.1
CLT: 1.0.0.9000000000.1.1249367152
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 4.2 build 425
X11: 2.6.5 => /usr/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
```

Full console output when I try to install 32-bit OpenCV (warning, very large dump): http://pastebin.com/hwKzKLQX

The [issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18139) brew mentions doesn't help.

Is someone able to interpret this and tell me what part of the build process is going wrong? How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it's trying to link against 32-bit versions of FFMPEG or similar libraries but not finding them. 32-bit programs need to be linked against 32-bit versions of all their libraries.  Those libs were probably built 64-bit only. The key errors look like this.

```
ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

Your error message output is kind of wonky and garbled from what looks like parallel make jobs interleaving their output. Use the single-job version described in the [Homebrew Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Troubleshooting) to make debugging easier.

This looks like a problem with the formula and dependency definitions that's distinct from the one you linked (which is about the `--32-bit` switch not attempting to build a 32-bit binary in the first place). The fix is to probably go through all the libs that OpenCV depends on (along with their dependencies, transitively) and reinstall them with the `--universal` switch, too. The default would probably have been to build only 64-bit versions of them. Homebrew does not have a mechanism to express dependencies on bitness or other build options (e.g. `--universal`) of packages something is indirectly dependent on.

When running `brew install opencv --universal` on OS X 10.8.3, I was able to reproduce similar link errors, complaining about symbols in libjpeg, and when I rebuilt jpeg with `--universal`, they cleared up, only to be replaced by other link errors, which cleared up with `--universal` rebuilds of other libraries, eventually producing a 32-bit opencv build. This thing links against a lot of libs.

Here's the process:

- Build opencv in single-job mode.
- Identify the library file it failed to link against. It's probably the one in the "ignoring" message.
- Determine what package that file is from. Check it and its parent dirs to see where they're symlinked in to `Cellar`
- Rebuild that package, and its dependencies if necessary, with `--universal`
- Repeat until all the link errors finally disapper

There's possibly an easier way. When `brew` is automatically installing dependencies, it'll propagate the `--universal` switch. So you can try removing *all* your homebrew packages (make a list of them first), then install just opencv with `brew install opencv --universal` and let it pick up all its transitive dependencies and make them universal too, and then install the rest of your packages back. (If you keep the list in a text file, you'll be able to pipe it to `brew` pretty easily.)

This is probably worth reporting as a new issue on the [Homebrew issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Troubleshooting). They can help you sort it out, and maybe improve the `--universal` checking of indirect dependencies, if that's what's going on here. Or it may be that the dependency checking is defeated by the fact that opencv itself is being built with `--32-bit` and not the more common `--universal`.

Comment: Great answer thanks - I'm going to follow these instructions through and will let you know if I have more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try `--universal` option when install